# recognize hash tags in twitter statuses

Tags: php

So I am parsing twitter statuses using PHP and I want to write code that recognizes whether the person added a specific tag (#php). The code always searches for the #php tag and determines whether the person added the tag. I am only searching for the #php tag. How can I write such a code in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `preg_match()`:

```
$has_php = preg_match('/#php\b/i', $tweet);
```

It's case-insensitive.

Comment: Though it's definitely a nice solution, I think using `regex` here generates a significant overhead when you can do this with PHP's native string library too (`stripos`).

Comment: The other strpos solutions will cause false positives though as Floern stated previously, matching #phpfoo

Comment: @tim-van-elsloo The OP asked for a solution for detecting exactly "#php" -- using `stripos` doesn't actually solve the problem -- a string containing "#php5" shouldn't be matched.

Comment: @Doches, that's true, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

`$has_hash = (boolean) strpos($status, '#php');`

Comment: This will cause a false-positive at `#phpfoo` or a false-negative at `#php` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on @daGrevis ones, but fixes two bugs:

```
$has_hash = (($has_hash = stripos($status, '#php')) !== false && $has_hash >= 0);
```

This will also return true if the `$status` begins with `#php`. If you use just `strpos`, it would return false, since it's position is `0` (`== false`) and it also returns true if `#Php` or something is found (case insensitive).

Comment: No it won't. `stripos('Lorum Ipsum', '#php') => -1`, `(-1 >= 0) => false` so `$has_hash => false`.

Comment: From Docs: stripos() "Returns the position as an integer. If needle is not found, stripos() will return boolean FALSE."; So `stripos('Lorum Ipsum', '#php') => false`, `(false >= 0) => true` so `$has_hash => true`

Comment: @Floern, didn't know that, I'm sorry. Updated my answer.